# VC++ Threads executing in Series & not in Parallel

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, parallel-processing

Please have a look at the following code:

```
 ThreadX^ o1 = gcnew ThreadX(SS,x2,0,ss,x,xcores);
     Thread^ t1 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(o1, &ThreadX::InitializeCvecArray));
     t1->Name = "t1";


     ThreadX^ o2 = gcnew ThreadX(SS2,x2,ss,ss,y,xcores);
     Thread^ t2 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(o1, &ThreadX::InitializeCvecArray));
     t2->Name = "t2";

     t1->Start();
     t2->Start();
```

The problem is that these threads execute in a series, first Thread t1 is executed and then thread t2 is executed. If I exit main (without calling Join()) after the line t2->start(); I only see output from t1 & not t2. These two threads are independent of each other, they read 2 or 3 global variables and that's it.

**Background Story**
I was running some cilk plus (intel cilk) code and I noticed that the time taken by the cilk program was equal to the time taken by the serial program + cilk overhead. So I created this simple threaded application and the results didn't change. The time taken by the threaded application is equal to the time taken by the serial program + thread creation/wait overhead.  I have an AMD Athlon 64 X2 system (simply 2 physical cores), Using Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit. I don't know any other language than C/C++.

**Extra Info**
Increasing the priority of the threads "t2->Priority = ThreadPriority::Highest;" didn't help either. What I want to do is compare a set of files with a reference one. To make the comparison faster I thought it would be nice if I compare two or more in parallel, hence the multi-threaded approach.

Comment: t2 is *meant* to be in o1 right?

Comment: Stupid question I know, but Win7 does show two cores available in Task Manager right?

Comment: Ahhh Tahnkyou Will & Will...
@Will : you just mentioned it, t2 is meant for o2 not o1. There is the mistake, am passing the object o1 to both.

Comment: @WillBickford Yes there are two cores in task manager :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Will noted in the comments, this line is the culprit:

```
Thread^ t2 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(o1, &ThreadX::InitializeCvecArray));
```

`o1` should be `o2` here.